# Session variable still undeclared between pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have created a LoginPage.php with the following code

```
<?
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');          
}   
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <?php 
    include("indexhead.php"); 
    ?>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php
        include("myCarousel.php");
        echo "
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'>

                 <h1 class='text-center login-title'>Sign in to continue:</h1>
                    <div class='account-wall'>

                        <form class='form-signin' method='POST'>

                            <input name='uid' type='text' class='form-control' 
                            placeholder='Username' required autofocus >
                            <input name='pass' type='password' class='form-control' 
                            placeholder='Password' required >

                            <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' type='submit'>
                            Sign in</button>

                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         ";

    if (isset($_POST['uid']) and isset($_POST['pass']))
    {
        if (empty($_POST['uid']) or empty($_POST['pass']))
        { 
            echo "Please type data into the login";                 
        }
        else
        {
                $uname = stripslashes($_POST['uid']);
                $pass = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
                $nick = selectSpecific("select nickName from hera.LoginTable where uid ='".$uname.
                "' and pass = md5('".$pass."');");
                if ($nick != '')
                {
                    $_SESSION['Nick1'] = selectSpecific("select nickName from hera.LoginTable where uid ='".$uname.
                    "' and pass = md5('".$pass."');");

                    $_SESSION['FullName'] = selectSpecific("select FullName from hera.LoginTable where uid ='".$uname.
                    "' and pass = md5('".$pass."');");

                    $_SESSION['dept'] = selectSpecific("select dept from hera.LoginTable where uid ='".$uname.
                    "' and pass = md5('".$pass."');");

                    $_SESSION['accesslevel'] = selectSpecific("select accesslevel from hera.LoginTable where uid ='".$uname.
                    "' and pass = md5('".$pass."');");

                    $_SESSION['uid'] = selectSpecific("select uid from hera.LoginTable where uid ='".$uname.
                    "' and pass = md5('".$pass."');");


                    header("Location: index.php");
                    //echo $_SESSION['Nick1'];

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Unknown Username/Password";
                }
        }   
    }   
 ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

what it does is to check the login and when the login is successful the user is lead to the index.php of the website

however, The index.php page does not detect the $_SESSION[''] variables, namely `$_SESSION['uid']` it says : Notice: Undefined index: uid in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hera\index.php on line 14

But I can confirm that the session variable does receive content from function selectSpecific().  Why is it not being held by the session?

here is the code for the index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    echo $_SESSION['uid'];

?>
```

Comment: instead of using header top of the page echo the $_SESSION['uid']  and see what value it is getting

Comment: can you check is your query OK? `echo "test = " . selectSpecific("select uid from hera.LoginTable where uid ='".$uname.
                    "' and pass = md5('".$pass."');"); exit; ` before `$_SESSION['uid'] = ...` line

Comment: also it would be much eaysier for you if you could fetch whole row from database like `$_SESSION['user'] = selectRow("select * from hera.LoginTable where uid ='".$uname.
                    "' and pass = md5('".$pass."');");` (assuming you have selectRow function) - fetching column after column from database is bad practice

Comment: @rahulmishra it echoes the exact value I needed

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest breaking this down to the simplest possible iteration and just have 1 page with session initialize

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['uid'] = 12345;
```

and another with the echo.

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

If that comes up empty then something is going on with the [PHP session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) (lots of good info here).

Also make sure a session is established.  By default it should use cookies (session.use_cookies = 1 in php.ini), so you should see a "PHPSESSID" cookie set.  Without that there is no way to actually have a session.

Comment: Will do matt as soon as I get back on the proj

Comment: It outputs array(0) { }

Comment: session.use_cookies = 1 is set in php.ini

Comment: In that case, do you see a cookie getting set during your first page call?  Use the developer tools in your browser (Chrome or Firebug in Firefox) to check the cookies.

Also are you running this on your own server or just locally?  Windows, *nix, Mac?

Comment: It's alright matt.. the session is working now. I made a very newbie mistake of forgetting to put '<?php' on the first part of the code

Answer (score 0):

first check your session value and than change your `html` like below you have not given name to submit button

```
 <form class='form-signin' method='POST'>

                            <input name='uid' type='text' class='form-control' 
                            placeholder='Username' required autofocus >
                            <input name='pass' type='password' class='form-control' 
                            placeholder='Password' required >

                            <input class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' type='submit' name='submit'/>
```

than change your php's `if condition` like below

```
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
         {
       if(isset($_POST['uid']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
        {
            if (empty($_POST['uid']) || empty($_POST['pass']))
            { 
                echo "Please type data into the login";                 
            } else
                 {       
                $uname = stripslashes($_POST['uid']);
                $pass = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);

         $nick =mysqli_query("select * from `hera.LoginTable` where `uid` ='".$uname."' and `pass` = '".md5($pass)."'","$dbcon");
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($nick);
                if ($rowcount==1)
                {
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    $_SESSION['Nick1'] = $row['Nick1'];

                    $_SESSION['FullName'] = $row['FullName'];

                    $_SESSION['dept'] = $row['dept'];

                    $_SESSION['accesslevel'] = $row['accesslevel'];

                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uid'];

                    header("Location: index.php");

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Unknown Username/Password";
                }
        }   
    }   }
    ?>
```

and using multiple query why don't use a single query like below

```
"select * from `hera.LoginTable` where `uid` ='".$uname.
                    "' and `pass` = '".md5($pass)."'");
```

Comment: I have no problem with determining login. My problem is with the session not working on the webpage I went to with header

Comment: value is still passed to $_SESSION when I use my function selectSpecific() however it doesn't to the page the header points to.

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to put `<?php` on the very top of my LoginForm.php file.